# Query CodeIgniter NOW() Sysdate() or .?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i have a problem with query SQL.
I need do a query that it result my order to last week ( 7days to now) I use this code

```
$this->db->where("account_orders.data > now()-7",NULL);
```

date in my db is -> 2019-04-05
Why don't it work ?

Comment: It probably doesn't know how to subtract `7` from a string. Is this `mysql` or what DB? `(NOW() - interval 7 day)` might do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why are using this `now()-7`, you can use range here with `where` clause if you want orders between 7 days to now, as:

```
$dateLastWeek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')); // last week day
$dateCurrent = date('Y-m-d'); // current day
```

**In CI,** you can use range as like:

```
$this->db->where("account_orders.data >=", $dateLastWeek);
$this->db->where("account_orders.data <=", $dateCurrent);
```

If you just need last week orders then, you can use just `$dateLastWeek` date in your query as:

```
$this->db->where("account_orders.data", $dateLastWeek);
```

**Note that,** i am using `Y-m-d` date format due your input which you mentioned in your question `2019-04-05`